# Cannot Find "Popularity Trends" and "Popularity and Search Reports"

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-analytics

According to Microsoft, the old Web Analytics in SharePoint 2010 is replaced in SharePoint 2013 by Popularity trends and it can by found under Site Settings as explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715890.aspx) and [here](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-2013-analytics)

However, I cannot find it in my farm.
Google provided me with [this usefule article](http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/#.V53TgIN94dV) on how to troubleshoot Popularity Trends issues.

But even after I applied every single step in the above article, I still cannot find the feature under site settings

Also I checked reporting service [as demonstrated here](http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-popularity-and-search.html?m=1) and it was Active. 
Even after I deactivated/activated it, nothing changed

The below is the expected view of site settings 
[image]
While the below is my farm view 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because **Reporting** feature was not activated in the site collection level. Go to **Site Settings**, click on **Site collection features** under **Site Collection Administration** section. Activate the **Reporting feature** now you can be able to see the Popularity Trends option in the document library interface.

Comment: I missed to mentioned that I did that as well, I will update the question with this hint